# cardinality of infinite sets with cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

claim: $A,B,C,D$ are infinite if $|A\times B|=|C\times D|$ then $|A|=|C|$, $|B|=|D|$ , prove or give a counter example.

So imo, the claim is false, using $A=D=\mathbb{R}$ , $B=C=\mathbb{N}$  ,
is it correct to say that |$\mathbb{R}$x$\mathbb{N}$|=$\aleph$ ? what are the guidelines to prove that?

Comment: it's given that A,B,C,D are infinite sets

Comment: Yes your example is fine. (I think you mean $|\Bbb R\times\Bbb N|={\frak c}$?) The guidelines to prove that I guess depend on what kinds of rules and facts you've covered..

Comment: Note that you don't need to prove that $|\mathbb R\times \mathbb N|=\aleph$. It's enough to prove that $|A|\neq |C|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly finer question might be whether $\lvert A \times B \rvert = \lvert C \times D \rvert$ implies $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert C \rvert$ and $\lvert B \rvert = \lvert D \rvert$, or $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert D \rvert$ and $\lvert B \rvert = \lvert C \rvert$.

However, assuming Choice, the cardinality of the product of two infinite sets is the largest cardinality of the two factors.  So if one takes $A = C = 2^{\mathbb{R}}$, $B = \mathbb{N}$, $D = \mathbb{R}$, we see that even this fails.

So (again under Choice) all one can infer from  $\lvert A \times B \rvert = \lvert C \times D \rvert$ is that *one of* $A, B$ will have the same cardinality as *one of* $C, D$.

Comment: And even without the axiom of choice, the example given by the OP works out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For any  sets *X* and *Y* (infinite or otherwise), $|X \times Y| = |Y \times X|$. This is easily demonstrated for non-empty sets by showing the existence of a bijection between $|X \times Y|$ and $|Y \times X|$, most obviously for example $(x, y) \leftrightarrow (y, x)$. On the other hand if either X or Y is empty, then $|X \times Y| = |Y \times X|$ = 0.

So, as in your example you can choose A = D = X, and B = C = Y and then $|A\times B|=|C\times D|$ as a consequence. If $|X| \ne |Y|$ then  $|A| \ne |C|$ and $|B| \ne |D|$.